# Error Qt QTemporaryDir when starting QGIS 3.25

Tags: qgis-3, installation, qt

After opening QGIS 3.25 appears a message on the top:

1-Qt: QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\QGIS3-aPRVXc" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.

2-Qt: QMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data An error has been encountered at line 1 of : Premature end of document.:

And after opening the project which was created in a older QGIS version (3.18):

1-Qt: QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\QGIS3-BfpVlZ" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.

2-Qt: QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\QGIS3-NyCfLL" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.

3-Qt: QTemporaryDir: Unable to remove "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\QGIS3-plEGeH" most likely due to the presence of read-only files.

4-Qt: QMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data An error has been encountered at line 1 of : Premature end of document.:

QGIS 3.25 is working correctly without any problems as i can see for now, but i don't understand the error.

Is this an installation problem?

Comment: Also happens in the Dev version -`QGIS version 3.27.0-Master QGIS code revision
b0d60567e5 Qt version 5.15.3` and you see `Qt: Retrying to obtain clipboard.` but everything seems to work fine.